# How can I add a PreferenceFragment in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

All my fragments are android.support.v4.app.Fragment and the Viewpager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter which also uses android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

I have a Fragment class which extends PreferenceFragment that I want to add in my Viewpager with my other two fragments.

How can I accomplish this?

Here's my ViewPager

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mFragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mFragmentsTitle.add(title);
}

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentsTitle.get(position);
}


}
```

Here's what I have in my PreferenceFragment

```
public class GameNotesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {


public GameNotesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_notes, container, false);
    return view;
}

}
```

When I try to add it in:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new GameNotesFragment(), "Note");
```

It gives me

```
Wrong firt argument com.example.fragments.GameNotesFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Problem is I can't add my PrefrenceFragment in the viewpager

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "I can't add my PrefrenceFragment in the viewpager"? Does it show a compile error? Or a runtime error (exception for example)? Second, I'm pretty sure you should not override `onCreateView(...)` in a `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: I edited my question. Please check it out!

Comment: You're using the wrong base class. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) extends the platform variant of the `Fragment` class. What you need is a [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html) that extends the support lib variant of `Fragment` (mind the different packages).

The support preferences require additional package(s) in your gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.0'
```

---

Also, while you're at it, make sure to check out the [bug fix lib](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) I created for the support preferences' common (and pretty annoying) bugs.

Comment: PreferenceFragmentCompat is not found do I need to change something my gradle?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the support preference package(s) to your gradle. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I forgot to accept your answer, sorry about that. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mFragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentsTitle.add(title);
    }

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment f = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            f = new GameNotesFragment();
        }

        if (position == 1) {
            f = new GameNotesFragment(); //replace your fragment 2
        }

        if (position == 2) {
            f = new GameNotesFragment();//replace your fragment 3
        }

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.name1);
            case 1:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.name2);
            case 2:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.name3);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in activity:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager());
tabLayout = v1.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
```